# How To Import exe file into resources Extract exe from resources and then shell

Tags: delphi, file, resources, runtime, extract

i want to import exe file into my delphi application resources.
and then extract and run the exe.

my qustion is:
how can i:
Import exe file into my resources 
Extract exe file into "c:\" (with `SaveToFile` function)
Run (`Shell exeFilePath`) the exe.

Comment: 3 questions in one? Since when was that allowed? Each of these is its own question, each of which has been asked/answered many times, and there's plenty of resources out there about it. 1: "How do I embed an EXE file inside my application?"; 2: "How do I extract an embedded EXE resource from my application?"; 3: "How do I execute another program from my application?"

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943364/723693) for an example how to include an file as a resource to your app. The example there is for a text file but it is the same idea for the exe file. It also shows you how to load that resource into an `TResourceStream` and then you just use it's [`SaveToFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TCustomMemoryStream.SaveToFile) method to save the exe to the disc. Once you have the exe on the disc you can run it with ie [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

there are component libraries allow you tou store your file on the from, inside DFMs

For example if installed [JediVCL](http://jvcl.sf.net) you can drop the [`TJvDataEmbedded`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvDataEmbedded) component onto the `TDataModule` or `TForm` and load a file into it. Then in the runtime you can extract that file onto disk or into `TMemoryStream`.

---

About running - the most simple thing would be to call [`ShellExecute`](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=delphi%20shellexecute&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) function - read your Delphi help about it. Or you can use the class from Jedi CodeLib which allow you a lot of customizations. But you probably do not need it.